# How to use unsafe code in safe contex?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, unsafe, securestring

I need to use `SecureString` for a Microsoft's class and i found the following code on the [internet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fpintos/archive/2009/06/12/how-to-properly-convert-securestring-to-string.aspx):

```
public static class SecureStringExt
{
    public static SecureString ConvertToSecureString(this string password)
    {
        if (password == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("password");

        unsafe //Red highlighted line
        {
            fixed (char* passwordChars = password)
            {
                var securePassword = new SecureString(passwordChars, password.Length);
                securePassword.MakeReadOnly();
                return securePassword;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem is that the `unsafe` keyword keeps throwing me error saying `Cannot use unsafe construct in safe context`.
Unfortunately i couldn't find why is this happening...

**Note:**
The above code runs in LINQPad but not in VS2013 (with resharper).

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use unsafe here, you create secure string without unsafe code. Check my answer.

Comment: The documentation says you shouldn't use that constructor. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/176bafkd(v=vs.110).aspx Use the code @mybirthname gave in his answer

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I am not sure if you need unsafe code in that case (see answer of **@mybirthname**).

But when unsafe code is needed, it can be enabled in Project properties.

- In the main menu, click `Project` and then `<ProjectName> properties...`
- Click on the `Build` page.
- Select `Allow unsafe code`.

[image: Allow unsafe code]

Or one can specify [/unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0.aspx) compiler option explicitly.

Comment: Can that be declared?

Comment: @jww What do you mean?

Comment: By using attributes. Something like [Declarative Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kaacwy28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It seems better to turn it off on an as-needed basis, rather than turning it off everywhere.

Comment: @jww I completely agree that enabling unsafe compilation should be minimized. However I doubt that attributes will help with `unsafe {...}`. Compiler gives `error CS0227: Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe`. If you have an idea how to do it, let me know please.

Comment: that's what I was asking :)

Answer (score 11):

```
    public static SecureString GetSecureString(string password)
    {
        SecureString secureString = new SecureString();

        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            secureString.AppendChar(c);
        }

        secureString.MakeReadOnly();
        return secureString;
    }
```

You can make same thing without unsafe code.